# Configure Apache Ant to be used behind a proxy

Tags: java, ant, proxy

I am trying to configure Apache Ant to be used behind a proxy, I am using MAC OS El Capitan, and I have a bash_profile that I know is being sourced by my terminal, I have this in my bash_profile to configure ANT for the proxy:

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUserName=myproxyusername -Dhttp.proxyPassword=myproxypassword -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxyhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

After I open my terminal I can `echo $ANT_OPTS` and I can see it is being loaded, I also now that when running an Ant Script that is trying to download a URL it is indeed picking up ANT_OPTS because it is going thru the proxy, however every single time I am getting:

```
[get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407
```

It tries 3 times and then bails out. If I remove `ANT_OPTS` then I just get a time out error as expected.

I know the error code is telling me that my credentials are incorrect or not provided, but I have made sure they are correct, is there another way that the proxy credentials should be provided to `ANT_OPTS`?, I tried `-Dhttp.proxyUserName and -Dhttp.proxyUser` to no avail.

This is my ant version:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Bash requires ANT_OPTS to be fully quoted for it to be set:

```bsh
export ANT_OPTS='-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 ...'
```

Notice the single quotes surrounding the entire value.

Comment: Thanks I tried with quotes too, but I got the same result unfortunately